# How do you get the following in the equation below?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

How do you get the following results in this equation:

$-2a + b - c = 0$

$-3a - 4b + c = 0$

$\frac{a}{1*1-(-4)*(-1)}$ = $\frac{b}{(-3)*(-1)-(-2)*1}$ = $\frac{c}{(-2)*(-4)-(-3)*1}$

$\frac{a}{-3}$ = $\frac{b}{3+2}$ = $\frac{c}{8+3}$

Comment: Please do not use images in lieu of text: they can cause problems with some displays, they are generally not searchable within the site, and they are usually not compatible with accessibility software. Check this [Page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) to learn how to write equations properly.

Comment: The underlines result is also called Cramer's Rule. But your question is unclear.

Comment: Wait Lemme just change Everything!

Comment: All gud can you check again?

Comment: Linear combinations of the equations.... Consider first the sum of the two equations; what you get is the new equation : $-5a-3b=0$ that amounts to ; $-5a=3b$. From it, you can have the first part of the ratio : $\dfrac {a}{-3} = \dfrac {b}{5}$. And the same for the second part, by multiplying first equation by $4$. What you get is : $-11a=3c$ from which : $\dfrac {a}{-3} = \dfrac {c}{11}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** 
Attempt to solve the sytem:
$$-2a + b - c = 0 \tag1$$

$$-3a - 4b + c = 0 \tag2$$

(1)+(2)

$$-5a-3b=0 \Rightarrow a=\frac{-3b}{5}, b=\frac{-5a}{3} \tag 3$$

$a=\frac{-3b}{5}$ can also be written as $$\frac{a}{-3}=\frac{b}{5} $$

Substitute the value of $a$ in (1):

$$-2(\frac{3b}{5})+b=c$$

$$-2(\frac{-3b}{5})+b=c$$

$$\frac{11}{5}(b)=c \tag4$$

We know $b$ from (3), using that value in (4)
$$\frac{11}{5}(\frac{-5a}{3} )=c $$

$$\frac{c}{11}=\frac{a}{-3}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer m8. :))

Comment: @Utkarsh, you are most welcome.